# Converting data into 2 decimal places

Tags: vba, excel

Anybody knows how to convert or revise this code to convert its answer to two decimal places?

```
Range("H2:H" & lastCell1).Formula = "=E2/18.33/8"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is `=E2/18.33/8` a formula where you are dividing `E2` by `18.33` first and then again by `8`?

Comment: @Mrig Yes it is how it works.

Comment: What is the value in `E2`?

Comment: It is just a data, lets say 149.25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or this ...

```
Range("H2:H" & lastCell1).Formula = "=ROUND(E2/18.33/8,2)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("H2:H" & lastCell1)
MyRange.Formula = "=E2/18.33/8"
MyRange.NumberFormat = "#0.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can you this

```
Sheet("yourSheetName").range("yourRange").NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

but this only applies to visual. If you wana realy change number to two decimal places you need to round it by something like this.

```
Sheets("sheet3").Cells(6, 3).Value = Round(Sheets("sheet3").Cells(6, 3).Value, 2)
```

Where you using `Round` when second argument is number of decimal places

Edit: also as someone mentioned here, you can use same `ROUND` in formula...